# How to add a custom string based on condition in the email template?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, email, email-template

I have a requirement to automate Purchase Order Emails, meaning if an Opportunity is Closed Won, Sales Manager can click on 'Send PO Email' button, and then email template will be previewed by him.

In this case, I was able to generate successfully the template and all, I have one issue, the template comprises instruction for different departments like Support, Training etc. Now if the purchase order is just for training then the field for 'Instructions for Support' should not be populated. As in my template, I have caption:

```
Support: {!Closing Instructions for Suppport} 
Training: {!Closing Instructions for Training},
```

So in the above mentioned scenario the email template should have only 
`Training: {!Closing Instructions for Training}` and not `Support: {!Closing Instructions for Suppport}`  based on my condition field that the product is for training.

Could anyone please advice?

Thanks
Sarika Patel

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpkYAAQ?

Comment: Can you please explain ...what you meant, when you say- "Email template will be previewed by him"(sales Manager).  Would that mean before email sent, template  data will be available  to him, will values propulated ?  Also one more thing.. what I understand.. you want to 'Conditionally populate" field values in template ..rt ?

Comment: Yes, before email sent, template data will be available to him, with values propulated. And I want to conditionally populate field values in template.

Comment: @Ruslan Vekua - I had a look in that link but it does not work for me. In addition to that I even have a caption of what the instructions are all about in the tempate which i cannot hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with VF email template and use If conditions; Hope i didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: Uday - community etiquette is to at least give an example related to the OP